# React-Redux example has a non-pure function. I thought reducers had to be pure?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Redux says that actions handling the state (Reducers) [have to be pure](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions).

Looking at the React-Redux docs, though, they show how to add a new Todo task to the list of Todos and the function generates a new identifier for the new Todo task. This is obviously not pure. Calling the same function again will not result in the same output.

There is the example (from [this page](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)):

```
// redux/actions.js
import { ADD_TODO } from "./actionTypes";

let nextTodoId = 0;
export const addTodo = content => ({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  payload: {
    id: ++nextTodoId,
    content
  }
});

// ... other actions
```

Does that means I have to forget everything I learned so far?

Comment: That's not a reducer, that's an action creator.

Comment: Regardless this fact, that's React-Redux guide. It teaches how to use Redux with React, not how to use Redux. Even if there were problems with Redux code, I'd consider them oversimplifications.

Comment: That's part of our new React-Redux docs rewrite.  Note that the React-Redux docs are now available in a published site at https://react-redux.js.org .  Also, per the answer, that's an action creator and not a reducer.

Comment: @Leandro, ah! Yes. Well... they say to be careful as Actions and [Action Creators](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions#action-creators) are different.

Comment: @markerikson, actually the docs are correct on that specific point _"Our addTodo action creator looks like this:"_ It's a beginner's problem to distinguish between "action" and "action creator".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like that's an action creator, not a reducer. Action creators don't have to be pure.

> Action creators can also be asynchronous and have side-effects.

https://redux.js.org/basics/actions#action-creators